# Including third party header and footer

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small web app. My clients use it on their site. To make it look seamless (a part of their own site), they put my app inside an iframe on their website. This way I don't have to worry about the header and footer (branding/styling etc). Now for some reason, the specs have changed and now the app will not be inside iframe. This leads to the problem that I will have to maintain a consistent header and footer branding/styling for each client. I have many clients and it is not possible for me to maintain each one of them and keep it updated all the time.

So, I am trying to come up with solutions that will allow me to inherit the header and footer from client and use it on my site. I was thinking about telling the client to maintain a header and a footer html file (and maintain it as per their branding). I will then make an AJAX call and call their HTML content on my page. This way I never have to worry about header and footer.

What other ways you can suggest I can solve this problem? Any experiences with such situations? How did you deal with it?

I know this is not a specific programming question but I thought this is the best place to get answer.
Thanks

Comment: What is the server side software?

Comment: I am using PHP at my end.

Comment: Are these sites all on the same domain? Do these sites all run from the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP, I may recommend you include a "templates" directory and you can apply the template, based upon the client profile.

In general, store the client header and footer HTML file location in your Database, and look up which template to use.  Then in your PHP header file, include something like:

```
define('CLIENT_HEADER', '**header string returned from your database**');
define('CLIENT_FOOTER', '**footer string returned from your database**');

define('DEFAULT_HEADER', '**default header location in template dir**');
define('DEFAULT_FOOTER', '**default footer location in template dir**');

if (isset(CLIENT_HEADER)){
  include(CLIENT_HEADER);
} else {
  include(DEFAULT_HEADER);
}
     ...
       the body of your webpage
     ...
if (isset(CLIENT_FOOTER)){
  include(CLIENT_FOOTER);
} else {
  include(DEFAULT_FOOTER);
}
```

Of course, you would need to customize this to your particular application, but this would automatically load the proper header/footer once loaded into the database.  It don't think it will work if the header or footer file isn't located on the PHP server, unless you mess with the php.ini file (I'm not an expert at that level, maybe someone else can comment on that).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing your web app inside an `iframe` you can place the `header` and `footer` inside an `frame` in your web app.